# How to calculate denoised image quality?

Tags: python, opencv, noise

We have many parameter values for our denoiser and currently rate them by comparing the denoised image with a non-noised one. It was good for testing, but we're not supposed to have the non-noised image.
How can we rate the denoised image without a non-noised one as a reference?

Comment: [This](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/3211/how-can-i-measure-noise-and-sharpness-of-an-image) may help

Comment: What is the goal of this? The testing is supposed to be enough for validating the algorithm and its performance, assuming it was carried our correctly. You can expect to get similar performance with other data (again, assuming the testing was carried out correctly).